# Why is MDA not good for classifying spam emails for this Hewlett-Packard dataset?

Tags: r, classification, discriminant-analysis

My lecture mentions

---

We now focus on the CART procedure and the mail/spam data of Hewlett-Packard. This dataset contains $n=4601$ mails with 1813 spams among them and, for each mail, we have $p=57$ variables relative to some word frequencies, to some character frequencies and to sequences of capital characters. These data can be obtained with the command,

```
source("http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~xgendre/ens/m2se/tp3.R")
X <- DataSpam()
```

Our goal is to provide a supervised learning procedure. This time, there are 2 labels: "Mail" and "Spam".

---

The the lecture note said

> the **Multiple discriminant analysis** (MDA) can only provide a **limited** answer to this problem

---

Could you please give some hints/explanation for such statement?